# How to move activity up down on touch-android studio

Tags: android

I have created one application in android studio where after filling edittext after button click I am getting result text in textview. because length of content view get cut. I want that with touching view(activity) should move updown to see all content on view. image attached.

[image: Mobile activity content is attached]

Comment: Put your layout(xml data) into scroll view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ScrollView. it will scroll  automatically when view is bigger than device size.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- your  xml code-->
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks for your immediate reply I use codes and working fine but can I restrict movement of scroll up to content because empty space on scroll view is bigger which looks ugly.

Comment: remove padding and margin space from your view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Parent layout` as `Scrollview` but scrollview has exceed only one child layout.

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

For reference check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).